# Replacing all symbols in a javascript string

Tags: javascript

Hi all ia m trying to replace all characters of "+" in a string by using the code below:

```
var findValue = "+";
var re = new RegExp(findValue, 'g');
searchValueParam = searchValueParam.replace(re, " ");
```

However i recieve this exception:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: nothing to repeat
```

previously i applied just searchValueParam = searchValueParam.replace("+", " "); but that only replaces the first occurrence, not all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the code you have, replace

```
var findValue = '+';
```

with

```
var findValue = '\\+';
```

Plus has a special meaning (quantifier) in a regular expression. This is why we need to escape it with a backslash: \+. However, when you place this in a string, the backslash itself has to be escaped as it has a special meaning in a string. This is how we end up with '\\+'.

In conclusion, this

```
var re = new RegExp('\\+', 'g')
```

is equivalent to this

```
var re = /\+/g;
```

Answer (score 3):

For multiple replacements you need to use regex with the global (`g`) modifier, however `+` has a special meaning (the previous item 1 or more times), so it needs to be escaped.

```
searchValueParam = searchValueParam.replace(/\+/g,' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `+` sign:

```
searchValueParam.replace(/\+/g, " ");
```